# how to show hover effect on a image where i hover my mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have multiple images, on hover on particular image i want to apply on that image only, it should not effect on other image.

---

**More Explanation:**
In this example(http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AnsqI), suppose i have multiple images & want to apply the certain effect on only on that image where i hove my mouse.

---

I am using class attribute...

```
 <script>
        $(function() { 
 //For grid view hover effect
        $('.grid_content').hide()
        $('.grid_container').hover(  
                // Over
                        function() {
                            $('.grid_content').fadeIn();
                        }
                ,
                        // Out
                                function() {
                                    $('.grid_content').fadeOut();
                                }
                        );
                        //--js for grid view hover effect ends here
        });

    </script>
```

Something i have to apply like $this , i tried like(`$this.$('.grid_content').fadeOut();`)but it did not work.

Somebody please help me.

Comment: Just to clarify, it doesn't look like you have defined `$this`. In order to get a jQuery object, use `$(this)`. Obviously that's not the main problem here, but it's good to know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
$('.container').hover(function(){
  $('.content',this).fadeToggle();
});
```

Check this Demo http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BxbID

Comment: Thanks! testing and then let you know

Comment: @Sundara check the demo posted

Comment: @Sundara what do you mean by little stylish?

Comment: I mean to make little more attractive in look(applying other effects) ?

Comment: @Sundara I already make my work here :) ... I guess you have an answer to your question. To make more attractive that element search for other recurse like flip.

Answer (score 2):

You could consider using CSS and the `opacity` attribute (or `display`). You could progressively enhance the hover effect with CSS3's `transition` property as well. There isn't necessarily a need for JS here, and I only added five lines of CSS (unprefixed) to achieve the same effect.

> ```
> .content {
>   width: 100%;
>   height: 100%;
>   background: rgb(255,255,255,0.9);
>   padding: 5px 15px 10px 15px;
>   box-sizing: border-box;
>   opacity: 0;
>   transition: opacity .2s linear; /* CSS3 progressive enhancement */
> }
>
> .content:hover {
>   opacity: 1;
> }
> ```

Depending on how you organize your HTML, you may need to make modifications, but the concept is the same.

Check out the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NeEuP/1/

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to do this. You can either reference it using the this javascript keyword and surrounding it in a jQuery function:

```
$('.grid_container').hover(function(){
  $(this).fadeIn();
, function(){
   $(this).fadeOut();
});
```

Or you can:

```
$('.grid_container').hover(function(e){
   $(e.currentTarget).fadeIn();
, function(e){
   $(e.currentTarget)$(this).fadeOut();
});
```

... basically you're getting element through the event object. I personally prefer this method, because it's more flexible it doesn't depend on the actual scope (this depends on scope).